# how to copy specific output from command promt to a file?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, command-prompt

I know ">" and ">>" redirecting symbols would help to copy whole thing from command prompt , but how to copy a specific line with the required string ?

Comment: this should probably be edited to remove the python tag

Comment: I am trying to use it in subprocess , so its python related , when I try to use it inside subprocess like subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i D:\devaraj\KPIX_test2.ts -vf blackframe D:\devaraj\KPIX_test5.mp3 D:\devaraj\KPIX_test2.txt |find"frame"', shell=True) it says 'find"frame"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. works fine from command prompt though , please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux

```
someprogram | grep req_string
```

windows

```
someprogram | find "req_string"
```

linux, discard STDOUT, and grep STDERR

```
someprogram 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep req_string
```

windows, discard STDOUT, and find in STDERR

```
someprogram 2>&1 >NUL | find "req_string"
```

windows, discard STDOUT, find in STDERR and write to a file.

```
someprogram 2>&1 >NUL | find "req_string" > log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for d help, this works with STDOUT output, but I want it for STDERR

Comment: I updted the answer with a way to search stderr

Comment: thanks for d very quick reply , writing to null says "access denied " so I am writing to a file . but this is displaying the required content on command prompt rather than the file intended 
C:\Windows\System32>ffmpeg 2>&1 >D:\devaraj\info.txt | find "libavutil"
libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101

Comment: I tried ! it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: when I try to use it inside subprocee like              subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i D:\devaraj\KPIX_test2.ts -vf blackframe  D:\devaraj\KPIX_test5.mp3 D:\devaraj\KPIX_test2.txt |find"frame"', shell=True)        it says 'find"frame"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.    works fine from command prompt though , please help!

Comment: @DevarajGH is there a space missing? `find"frame"` should be `find "frame"`.